# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth$1.class

Tags: android, firebase

I want to apply the leaderboard to my game. I am getting so many  error like no firebase class exception & if I added the firebase libary then i am receiving this type of message.  Please help me.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile project(':BaseGameUtils')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-server-sdk:3.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Can u post your updated gradle file after Ram's suggestions? and try this remove the whole gms dependency i.e., com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0 and use only those required

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to include the Firebase SDK for Java servers into your Android app. That won't work.

Remove this line:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-server-sdk:3.0.1'
```

And the error will disappear.

Then add tis line to use Firebase Authentication for Android:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'
```

In general, I recommend following the steps in the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Answer (score -1):

Add below code to your build.gradle file

```
android {

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}
```

Comment: Its not fixing my issue Ram

Comment: Is BaseGameUtils module gradle file have com.google.firebase:firebase-server-sdk:3.0.1 dependency or have u added firebase as lib in libs folder??

Comment: no. But if i executing the project i am getting no firebase exception that the reason i added the firebase library

Comment: Remove one of them so that project can compile properly

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions

Comment: Go through google doc there they mentioned like
// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: You said you get java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions when you install. Are you using ProGuard? The classes might have been removed from the release .apk if you are using ProGuard and did not configure it.